# Why is HttpClient so much faster with HTTPS over HTTP?

Tags: c#, .net, http, https, dotnet-httpclient

I was investigating a strange bug the other day in which normalizing a URL would cause a massive 300% slowdown in my application:

```
if (!TryNormalize(uri, out uri))
    throw new ArgumentException("URL is not a valid YouTube URL!");

string pageSource;

using (var http = new HttpClient())
    pageSource = await http.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

When `TryNormalize` was commented out, `GetStringAsync` would take about .5s to complete. Yet when it was uncommented, downloading the string would take up to 2s. Turns out that `TryNormalize` was prefixing all the URLs it processed with `"http://"`, and adding an extra `S` solved the problem.

So with that said, why does this happen? To my understanding, HTTPS should be slower because the string has to be encrypted before transmission from the server, while HTTP doesn't offer such an option. And even if I'm no expert on HTTP, 300% seems like quite a dramatic slowdown. Am I missing something here?

---

**Edit:** Source code of `TryNormalize`:

```
public static bool TryNormalize(string videoUri, out string normalized)
{
    normalized = null;

    var builder = new StringBuilder(videoUri);

    videoUri = builder.Replace("youtu.be/", "youtube.com/watch?v=")
        .Replace("youtube.com/embed/", "youtube.com/watch?v=")
        .Replace("/v/", "/watch?v=")
        .Replace("/watch#", "/watch?")
        .ToString();

    string value;

    if (!Query.TryGetParamValue("v", videoUri, out value))
        return false;

    normalized = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=" + value; // replacing with HTTPS here results in 1.5s speedup
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is `TryNormalize` ?

Comment: Are you behind an evil packet shaper that might be prioritizing https traffic differently than http?

Comment: @Eser Apologies. Updated my sample in response. It's basically a method to convert un-standard YouTube URLs (e.g. `watch#v=`) to `watch?v=`.

Comment: Sounds like there's something in the network impacting performance outside of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there are many redirections when you use the variantions of youtube url. For example navigating to `http://youtu.be/O3UBOOZw-FE` results in two redirections.(see the **Location** header)

1.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 16:52:40 GMT
Server: gwiseguy/2.0
Location: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3UBOOZw-FE&feature=youtu.be
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

2.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 16:52:40 GMT
Server: gwiseguy/2.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube
Location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3UBOOZw-FE&feature=youtu.be
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

until you finally  get the url `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3UBOOZw-FE&feature=youtu.be`

Since those redirections are handled automatically by `HttpClient`, you only see the final result of 3 requests.

Comment: Thanks, great answer!